# Laravel: Delete all except latest 5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make this query work:

```
$deleteSubmissions = ViewedSubmission::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->latest()
    ->skip(5)
    ->delete();
```

I want to delete all ViewedSubmissions records for the auth user EXCEPT for the latest 5. How can I make this work? Currently this doesn't delete anything, despite having more than 5 records.

Comment: Can you indicate what `latest()` does? I presume it's a scope - is it ordering by `created_at`?

Comment: The latest and oldest methods allow you to easily order results by date. By default, result will be ordered by the created_at column

Answer (score 7):

I'd handle it this way:

```
$keep = ViewedSubmission::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->latest()
    ->take(5)
    ->pluck('id');

ViewedSubmission::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $keep)
    ->delete();
```

Comment: This is similar to how I would have done it, however I was hoping to reduce it to a single ->delete() query in order to minimize total database queries. Is there not a simpler way?

Comment: @FelixMaxime Properly indexed, these two queries should take virtually no time.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: You can select latest 5 records with except of given array then deleted.

```
$except = 5;
ViewedSubmission::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->latest()
    ->skip($except)
    ->get()
    ->each(function($row){ $row->delete(); });
```

And if you has a relation with user id (one to many) named for example `viewedSubmissions` you can do it like that:

```
$except = 5;
Auth::user()->viewedSubmissions()
    ->latest()
    ->skip($except)
    ->get()
    ->each(function($row){ $row->delete(); });
```